# Cannot shutdown/restart properly, force-quit fails, wunderlisthelper does not die

Tags: macos, shutdown, force-quit

Alright, I had another initial post draft written, but then I just found something:

wunderlisthelper will not die...

**kill -9** will cause it to reopen with **another pid**.
I keep hard killing it, and it keeps jumping to a new process.

```
91617 ??         0:00.55 QA2G25RMZ4.com.wunderkinder.wunderlist-helper
```

What is this?

The initial prob is that shutdown/restart will work if not logged in, but will not work if logged into any account. I've tried MANY methods to solve the issue - nothing yet. All other diagnostics (hardware and software) are good.

Also fwiw there is some trouble with force-quit other apps, but maybe unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wunderlisthelper runs in the background and restarts automatically due to the loaded launch agent. You can disable it from Wunderlist preferences.

[image]

Comment: Alright, with troubleshooting exhaustion I was hoping I found the problem. Keep going... Thanks for the answer